# Can I instantiate an std::reference_wrapper<T> where T is an incomplete type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, incomplete-type

Does `std::reference_wrapper<T>` allow `T` to be incomplete, in the same way that a `T&` can be dealt with without `T` being complete?

GCC 4.9 accepts the following:

```
#include <functional>

struct woof;

struct test
{
   test(woof& w) : w(w) {}
   std::reference_wrapper<woof> w;
};

struct woof
{
   int a;
};

int main()
{
    woof w;
    test t = w;   // (braced-init would be better, but VS2012!)
}
```

But MSVS 2012 rejects it with the following message:

> Error 1   error C2139: 'woof' : an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_abstract' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\type_traits  755 1   test3

I suspect this is because the `op()` needs the full type, but the standard doesn't *appear* to specify either way.

Which, if either, of these implementations is following standard mandates?

Comment: I have no idea but my bet isn't on MS

Comment: Note that MSVC fails regardless of what the standard says: [This program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a8e28dc279da2e5) doesn't compile on MSVC11+, thanks to the `is_abstract` test.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

N3936 §**17.6.4.8 Other functions [res.on.functions]**:

> 1 In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> 2 In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - ...
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
>   unless specifically allowed for that component.

A quick scan through **20.9.3 Class template `reference_wrapper` [refwrap]** reveals no such specific exception for `reference_wrapper`, so your program has undefined behavior. Both implementations are conforming.

Comment: Damn, too slow. +1 BTW: I think this is a case where an incomplete type should be allowed.

Comment: It seems that the only components with that special exception are the smart-pointer types. I think it would make a lot of sense to have it for `reference_wrapper` too, because it can be useful and is trivial to accomplish (since it's usually just a wrapper around a pointer, like smart-pointers). The whole incomplete-type question is a very weak point in the C++ standard (both for library components and rules about templates), it's in need of better specifications, like clearer rules and required diagnostics / errors instead of UB.

Comment: @Deduplicator The problem with allowing incomplete types is that `reference_wrapper` must comply with the old `unary_function`/`binary_function` protocol for backwards compatabiity. To do so, it needs to define various typedefs based on the type of the template parameter, e.g. [refwrap]/3: "The template instantiation ... shall define ... `argument_type` as a
synonym for `T1` only if the type `T` is any of the following:
... a class type with a member type `argument_type`; the type `T1` is `T::argument_type`.".