# enable_if + variadic templates: is it UB or a MSVC bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

GCC 4.9.2, clang 3.5.0 and MSVC 19 (x86) compile the following as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    tuple_for_each(tuple<Tp...> &)
{
    cout << sizeof...(Tp) << endl;
}

template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    tuple_for_each(tuple<Tp...> & t)
{
    tuple_for_each<I + 1, Tp...>(t);
}

int main()
{
    auto t = make_tuple(1, 2.3);
    tuple_for_each(t);
}
```

MSVC 18 (x64) instead reports the following:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
main.cpp(18) : error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'enable_if<I<0x01,void>::type tuple_for_each(std::tuple<_Types1...> &)'
        main.cpp(16) : see declaration of 'tuple_for_each'
        main.cpp(24) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void tuple_for_each<0x00,int,double>(std::tuple<int,double> &)' being compiled
main.cpp(18) : error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<I==0x01,void>::type tuple_for_each(std::tuple<_Types1...> &)'
        With the following template arguments:
        'I=0x01'
        'Tp={int, double}'
```

Is it UB somewhere or just a compiler bug? (If the latter, any workarounds?)

Comment: @Pradhan why not? i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26044156/396583

Comment: Ah, UB wrt standard library pre-conditions. I stand corrected.

Comment: This is obviously a compiler bug.

Comment: compiled and ran for me on clang, so I'm suspecting either a library bug or compiler bug.

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug: VC18 accepts similar code if we replace the parameter pack with another `size_t` non-type template parameter. The error message "invalid explicit template arguments(s)" also occurs when there's only a single function template that is deactivated by SFINAE via `enable_if`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp,
         typename = typename enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type, int = 0>
inline void tuple_for_each(tuple<Tp...> &)
{
    cout << sizeof...(Tp) << endl;
}

template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp,
         typename = typename enable_if<I != sizeof...(Tp), void>::type>
inline void tuple_for_each(tuple<Tp...> & t)
{
    tuple_for_each<I + 1, Tp...>(t);
}
```

---

Note the `!=` in `I != sizeof...(Tp)`. Try `<`, and you'll see:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
main.cpp(27) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

which is magnificent on its own. (GCC and Clang both work with `<`, but not MSVC19 this time.)

---

Trying to use

```
template <bool B, typename T> using enable_alias = typename enable_if<B, T>::type;
```

with the initial variant ends up in an ICE at all:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocnum(1105) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\outdname.c', line 4155)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```